# Proof prefix fact

Tags: logic, proof-writing, formal-languages

Let $\Sigma$ be the set of letters from the alphabet, so $\Sigma = \{a,b,c,d,...\}$.
The set of prefixes of a word $w \in \Sigma^*$ is:
$$pre(w):=\{u \in \Sigma^* | \exists v \in \Sigma^* : uv = w\}$$

Example: $$pre(aab)=\{\Lambda, a, aa, aab\}$$

Prove that

For all $x,y \in \Sigma^*, pre(xy)=pre(x)\cup\{x\}pre(y)$

by showing that

$pre(xy) \subseteq pre(x)\cup \{x\}pre(y)$

$pre(x)\cup \{x\}pre(y) \subseteq  pre(xy) $

---

Concatenation of two languages (Read: sets of words) is defined as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfQ6v.png)

Comment: You've only defined $pre(w)$ not $pre(S)$ whwre $S$ is a set, so your example is assuming that $$pre(S)=\bigcup_{w\in S} pre(w)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $|u|$ denote the length of a word $u$.

**Hint**. Let $p$ be a prefix of $xy$. If $|p| \leqslant |x|$, then $p$ is a prefix of $x$. If $|p| \geqslant |x|$, then $x$ is prefix of $p$ and hence $p = xp'$ where $p'$ is a prefix of $y$.